# ignore files which have not been ignored

Tags: git

In the past, I add and upload all files in my working directory. 
Now I want to ignore some files, so I create a file `.gitignore` directly in my working directory `myproject`, with content:

```
build/
*~
```

Then I run

```
git add -A .
git commit -m 'add ignore files'
git push origin master
```

But the destination repository still has those files I want to ignore. Also `.gitignore` is also shown in the destination repository. I wonder if I do it correctly?

Should I put `.gitignore` in `myproject` or `myproject/.git`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to ignore already committed files. In this case you may need to remove them from cache:

> git rm --cached build/

Comment: Thanks. Will that remove the files and dirs in my working directory?

Comment: Should I also hide or ignore .gitignore? and how?

Comment: it will remove the file from the stage

Comment: hide .gitignore? hm... when you commit .gitignore file, it won't be seen anymore; if you want to ignore file outside of your git repo, use .git/info/exclude instead.

Comment: in the destination of git push, I still see `.gitignore`. Shall I also run `git rm --cached .gitignore`? Is it generally assumed that each repository has its own `.gitignore` file and this file is not pushed?

Comment: even after git rm .gitignore; git push?

Comment: I haven't run either `git rm --cached .gitignore` or `git rm .gitignore`, but `git rm --cached build/ *~`. Shall I run either of `git rm --cached .gitignore` or `git rm .gitignore`?

Comment: If you want to *remove* file from repository, start with `git rm .gitignore`

Comment: I don't know if I want. What do people in general do with .gitignore in their working directories: push it with other files to other repositories, or remove it from their local repositories by `git rm .gitignore`?

Comment: it depends: usually you push it, but if you think those changes won't be interested for other repository contributors, you keep it local of use *.git/info/exclude*